# How do work on a flutter code that uses an old flutter sdk?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I just started working as a freelancer, as a flutter developer. I keep getting job offers, where I'm needed to make changes to their already developed app. But I have one issue they code is of an earlier version and the code won't run, what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to get https://fvm.app (The Flutter Version Manager), which can install any past version of Flutter, and permit per-project version settings.  Once it's set up (a little tricky), it's very easy to use.  Far better than constantly clobbering your one installation of Flutter with old and new versions!

EDIT: these days, I highly recommend [Puro](https://puro.dev) over FVM.  It's faster, cleaner, uses a lot less disk for multiple versions, works better with the main IDEs, and even has a one-line Dart eval!

Answer (score 1):

What works for me:

- flutter downgrade 2.16.1 or any version you need
- reset IDE
- flutter clean
- delete /ios/Pods
- delete /ios/Podfile.lock
- flutter pub get
- from inside ios folder: pod install
- flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Flutter gives you the option to download the version you need

- You can download the version of Flutter you need from this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)
- unzip it
- change the existing Flutter path to point to the new one
- run `flutter doctor`